# What would be the minimum group size for The Enemy Within?

Tags: published-adventures, wfrp-1e

I plan to GM The Enemy Within campaign for WFRP 1st Edition. I'm new to GMing and need to form a group of players. What would be the smallest or best group size?

I see in the 1E rulebook they recommend at least 2 players. Is this the same for TEW? It is worth noting that a Facebook group for WFRP 1E has suggested 2 players playing 2 characters each.

Note that I am looking for the minimum group size while still staying true to the sourcebook.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please take the [tour] to learn about the site. I have edited the question to remove signalled edits. On this site edits are not signalled in the posts and [edit history](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/138722/revisions) is available instead. Happy gaming!

Answer (score 1):

I've run this campaign a few times and wouldn't even attempt to run it with less than 3 characters and would recommend a minimum of 4 (assume that on some game sessions one person can't make it).

The various challenges in the campaign require different skills that you are unlikely to find in a too-small group. And in various encounters the groups can be easily wiped out if there are only 2 of them and they have unlucky dice.

As far as I remember there is no officially stated minimum, but the campaign was clearly written with a normal group of characters in mind, i.e. about 4 characters with diverse skills.